# What % of the products has a shelf life of 5 days or more?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

Shelf life (in days) of a product is exponentially distributed. Further 22.31 % of these products have last 3 days or more. What % of the products has a shelf life of 5 days or more?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: I believe any answer would be some partial copy paste from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) (that or will directly give you the result). You'll probably be able to solve it from there.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{3}^{\infty} \lambda e^{-\lambda x} dx = 0.2231$$

$$e^{-3\lambda} = 0.2231$$

$$\lambda = -\frac{ln(0.2231)}{3}$$

$$\lambda = 0.5$$

$$P(X\ge 5) = \int_{5}^{\infty} 0.5 e^{-0.5 x} dx$$

$$ = e^{-5*0.5} = 0.08206=8.206\text{%}$$